# How to group markers on earth 3D using WebGL

Tags: 3d, leaflet

I have a problem about the earth map with 3D. Currently, I am using WebGLearth to create the 3D earth map ([here is my demo](http://overfull.net/viewer/3d/)). But I'd like to add some markers that would be grouped by a counter [like in this demo made by leaflet](http://overfull.net/viewer/2d/). I tried to make it with no result. 
Is it possible or is there a better library in which could customize some logic and icons ?

Comment: What do you mean with "better" library ? WebGL earth is anyway leaflet compatibel.

Comment: But I can't add the counter grouped as 2D demo on my 3D demo?

Comment: creating a fiddle with these two examples would help